# Android Pass data from notification to activity

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-bundle, pass-data

Everyone
I am using this 
***PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);***
to pass data from notification to activity but I still get the last data every time I am really confused why this is happening, because I think give a unique id to pending intent is not a valid way to pass data
thanks
any help is highly appreciable

Comment: Did you try the onNewIntent callback? . Also, posting code snippets of what you have tried would help to answer the questions better

Comment: Yes I tried it but still no result

Comment: Could you share the code that you tried?

Comment: Intent pendingIntentForActivity = new Intent(this, ParentActivity.class);
pendingIntentForActivity.putExtra("isFromPush", false);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, pendingIntentForActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you use to "pass data" (ie: how are you putting the data in the `PendingIntent`. Don't add code as a comment, it doesn't format and is hard to read. Just edit your question and paste the code there.